# Why getting g++ not recognized as a command while running subprocess in python?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, subprocess, g++

I have an online ide which takes code and language from the user and upon submitting the server has to execute the file. I have g++ installed on my system still upon execution I get the following error in subprocess module:

```
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The function for file execution is :

```
def execute_file(file_name,language):
    if(language=="cpp"):
        #g++ xyz.cpp
        subprocess.call(["g++","code/" + file_name],shell=True)    #this only compiles the code
        subprocess.call(["./a.out"],shell=True)          #this executes the compiled file.
```

my code file is there in the /code directory.

The directory structure is :

[image]

Comment: When you use `shell=True` `subprocess.call` expects the command to be a string instead of a `list` or `tuple`

Comment: @Clasherkasten I removed ```shell=true``` but I am getting ```FileNotFoundError: The system cannot find the file``` even though the file exists and is there inside ```/code``` directory .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The conflict was resolved after I specified the removed the `shell=True` and specified the absolute path of the file using the `os module`.